# Linearising thermal radiation

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-system

I'm trying to linearise in real time (part of a simulink simulation) radiative resistances. What I've done is the following:

> Radiative law: $$P=\frac{\Delta T^4}{R_r}$$
>
> At any given timestep, I know what the temperature difference across
>   the radiative resistance is, so I know the power $P$ running through
>   it. From the convective law, I then know that: $$R_{c,eq}(\Delta T)=\frac{\Delta T}{P}=\frac{R_r}{\Delta T^3}$$

However, it's not coherent with the result I get when using the tangent method:

> [image] $$\frac{1}{R_{c,eq}}(\Delta T)=\frac{dP}{d(\Delta T)}(\Delta T)=\frac{4\Delta T^3}{R_r}$$
>   $$\Rightarrow  R_{c,eq}(\Delta T)=\frac{R_r}{4\Delta T^3}$$

There is a factor 4 between those two results, which is right and why are they different?

Comment: This might be better for a physics forum.

Comment: Already tried it, didn't have any answer so I thought maybe it was a maths problem. It seems we won't know which forum is the best suited before the answer is known...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A radiative resistance is always *between two*
bodies $(i,j)$ with a *temperature difference*. In general,
the flow of heat between $(i)$ and $(j)$ has the form:
$$
Q_{j\rightarrow i} = \sigma\cdot A_{i,j}\left(Tj^4-T_i^4\right)
$$

- $\sigma = 5.73 \times 10^{-8} W/m^2/K^4$ (Stefan-Bolzmann constant)
- $A_{i,j} = $ factor with dimension of area $[m^2]$,
  dependent on emission coefficients, radiative areas and, last but not least:
  [view factors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_factor) .
- $T = $ temperature

There is a [Wikipedia reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_radiation#Radiative_heat_transfer) about all this.

The heat flow can be written as the admittance $\gamma_{i,j}$ of a resistor,
times the temperature difference:
$$
Q_{j\rightarrow i} = \gamma_{i,j}\left(Tj-T_i\right)
$$
Where the admittance - though linearized reasonably well - is still dependent
on the temperatures:
$$
\gamma_{i,j} = \sigma\cdot A_{i,j}\left(Tj^2+T_i^2\right)\left(Tj+T_i\right)
$$
So iterations may be necessary, but the hard part is in $A_{i,j}$ and the view factors, most of the time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, turns out the only thing I hadn't checked was the law itself...